# Angular: Cant define router outlet in lazy loaded module component:

Tags: angular, routes

I want to make lazy loaded module in which i have 3 components. The main is Auth component(and signIn and signOut component). So i make the lazy loading and i load my module lazily, but i cant define router-outlet tag in my auth component to make child routes work.

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthorizationModule} from './authorization/authorization.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthorizationModule}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {SignUpComponent} from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import {SignInComponent} from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import {AuthComponent} from './auth/auth.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AuthComponent, children: [
      {path: 'signIn', component: SignInComponent},
      {path: 'signUp', component: SignUpComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AuthRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ' i cant define router-outlet tag'?

Comment: when im trying to add <router-outlet> in my auth.component.html , the compiler says 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

Comment: is your AuthRoutingModule  module added as an import into AuthorizationModule module? and is AuthComponent declared into AuthorizationModule module?

Comment: Please Import your AuthRoutingModule  in AuthorizationModule.

Comment: i already imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide which version of angular you're using, anyway in your `AppRoutingModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [ {
           path: 'auth', 
           loadChildren:  () => import('./path/to/your/auth/module/ts/file').then((m: AuthModule) => m.AuthModule)
       }
];
```

Comment: i solved that problem. I forget import AuthComponent in my AuthRouting, sorry for this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Import `AuthRoutingModule` in your `AuthorizationModule`

```
@NgModule({
  
  imports: [
    AuthRoutingModule // Add this statement
  ]
})
export class AuthorizationModule{ }
```

Comment: Have you did the same in AppModule (Adding AppRoutingModule )

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ercsb8-eqz5vu please use this stackblitz for answer. there are few errors
1. you need to declare auth component in auth module
2. since you have used router-outlet in auth component, either you need to provide a default URL in routing or keep some route based buttons in auth component
3. router module import in app routing.ts can be done in better way please look at the stackblitz i have fixed all these issues

Comment: comment line number 12 in auth routing.ts and try to hit auth/signin or auth/signup urls

Comment: i solved that problem. I forget import AuthComponent in my AuthRouting, sorry for this, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark it as solved.. happy coding